# Outlook OoO send an email once a day

Tags: vba, powershell, outlook, scheduled-tasks, exchange-server

Outlook has a standard feature of sending Out of Office (OoO) messages when someone is away on holiday or absent.

Standard feature is having the OoO send only 1 message during the whole period the OoO is activated. You can make Outlook send a message to everyone for every mail that arrives by using a mail template by adding a rule in your OoO. (not recommended)

Sending a mail only once, is to little; sending a mail every time, is to much.

Is there a way to make the OoO send a mail that a person is absent only once a day per email address? (I am still wondering why this is not a standard feature in outlook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article, which describes a small PowerShell script that accomplishes exactly this by running it once each night.

http://san.schausberger.cc/2013/07/how-to-change-exchange-2010-out-of-office-ooo-oof-interval/

It records the OOO state (enabled or disabled), sets the state to disabled + resets it to the previous recorded state. That retriggers the “OOO reply once” behavior.

```
$enabled = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited
|get-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration | where {$_.autoreplystate -eq
"enabled"} | select identity,autoreplystate $enabled | foreach-object
{ set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration $_.identity -autoreplystate
"Disabled" set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration $_.identity
-autoreplystate $_.autoreplystate }
```

With a little tweaking I’m sure you can modify it so that only mailboxes in the OZ mailbox store are affected.
It can then be set to run as a scheduled task :

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
-command “. ‘C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1′; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; c:\reset_outofoffice.ps1″
```